# SpriteKit - Draw dynamic line between Joints

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to programmatically build a pendulum using iOS SpriteKit using the built in physics.

Currently, I have the pendulum pivot, a weight, and a limited joint that allows the weight to swing... But, I have no idea on how to code a line (rod) between the pivot and weight.

I assume that drawing a line with SKShapeNode would be a start...?

```
-(void)setupPendulum
{
    pivot = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pivot.png"];
    pivot.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2);
    pivot.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:1.0];
    pivot.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    pivot.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    pivot.xScale = 0.25;
    pivot.yScale = 0.25;
    [self addChild:pivot];

    weight = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"weight.png"];
    weight.position = CGPointMake(150, 512);
    weight.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:100.0];
    weight.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    weight.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    weight.physicsBody.mass = 0.5;
    weight.xScale = 0.75;
    weight.yScale = 0.75;
    [self addChild:weight];

    SKPhysicsBody *ab = pivot.physicsBody;
    SKPhysicsBody *bb = weight.physicsBody;
    CGPoint ap = pivot.position;
    CGPoint bp = weight.position;
    SKPhysicsJointLimit *joints = [SKPhysicsJointLimit jointWithBodyA:ab
                                                                bodyB:bb
                                                              anchorA:ap
                                                              anchorB:bp];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:joints];
}
```

Comment: Correct,`SKShapeNode` is where you should start.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @prototypical, any guidance on how I would implement that correctly?

Comment: Personally, I'd start with the SpriteKit reference and programming guide for anything that I wanted to know more about. https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/OtherNodeClasses/OtherNodeClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH10-SW14

Comment: Sorry for not providing an example solution for you, but questions should be about things you have attempted to do and got stuck on, not as a substitute for taking proper first steps. I am sure that a search for `SKShapeNode example` on this site or via a google search will also provide a quick answer.

Comment: Actually, yes... I always look at the reference material before I ask a question to someone. BUT, your guidance on looking at SKShapeNode didn't help me figure out the answer... Looking at SKPhysicsJointPin got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My project required the `SKPhysicsJointLimit` instead of the pin so after a lot of trial and error I found the following solution. The line is removed and drawn in `didSimulatePhysics`. The line connects the "satelliteShip" as it orbits around the "motherShip". I'm new to all this so I appreciate any feedback on this approach.

Setup variable first:

```
SKShapeNode *_lineNode;
```

Now draw the line in didSimulatePhysics:

```
- (void)didSimulatePhysics {
    if (_lineNode){
        [_lineNode removeFromParent];
    }
    SKNode *satelliteShip = [self childNodeWithName:kSatelliteShipName];
    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw;
    pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, motherShip.position.x, motherShip.position.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, satelliteShip.position.x, satelliteShip.position.y);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathToDraw);

    _lineNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    _lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
    CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);
    _lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor grayColor];
    [self addChild:_lineNode];
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll give it a whirl soon and try to give you feedback. So far, looks like a great answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct direction was to look at **SKPhysicsJointPin**, which can use a SKShapeNode or SKSpriteNode (etc.).

https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJointPin_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

**Note About my question and the comments on it:**

*Since there isn't very much documentation (now) on SpriteKit beyond the (small book sized) reference by Apple and a grip of single-class-app examples/tutorials online -- most peoples responses are to, "just look it up + Cocos2d in google" and just re-do that. That's nice en all, but I'm not a copy-paste kinda of person. I like to learn the best way which is sustainable and reusable. This is why I asked what the best way to do it vs. posting busted Cocos2d ported copy-paste code and letting someone fill in the blanks like I see happen too often.*